# Parse Cloud - Set an attribute to data before being returned from cloud

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

```
query.find().then(function(data) {
  data.set("foo", "bar");
  response.success(data);
})
```

The above code does not return the whole object from cloud. It just returns 

`{ObjectId: 'something', className: 'something'}`

But when I remove the `data.set()` it works perfectly. `.set` method is available on data object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to save the object before returning from cloud. Once you have saved it, you will get the updated object.

```
    Parse.Cloud.define(“ShowEmail”, function(request, response) {
   
        var user = Parse.User.current();
        try{
            if(request.params.show){
                user.set("Show_Email",true);
            }else{
                user.set("Show_Email",false);
            }
            user.save(null, {
                success: function(returnUser) {
                    response.success(returnUser);
                },
                error: function(returnUser, error) {
                    response.error(returnUser);
                }
            });
 
        }catch(e){
            response.error(e.message);
        }
 
});
```

Comment: How come this is a solution? I am asking a way to extend the Parse Object that is being returned from cloud. What you are saying is a way to include the complete pointer object.

Comment: I have edited my answer, you need to save the object before returning from cloud. Hope that helps.

Comment: You actually did not mention anything at all about wanting to "extend" the object, only updating it.  @ZeeshanAnjum's answer is what I would recommend trying as well - hopefully you appreciate his effort.  Based on your comment, I recommend editing your question to be more clear on what it is that you actually want.

Comment: The updated answer does it. I don't understand why should I call save method on the data object after extending it. I mean why should it act like a promise ..